# Source a file to a HTTP Request using Conduits

Tags: haskell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yesod

I'm having trouble trying to construct a `RequestBody ResourceT IO`.
I'm newer to conduits and am trying to upload a file to S3 using the `aws` package.

```
io $ withManager $ \mgr ->
      do Aws.pureAws cfg s3cfg mgr $ S3.putObject stcompleted "job.zip" $ 
            RequestBodySourceChunked $ do
                  CB.sourceFile "job.zip"
```

And the type error I receive is this.

```
  Couldn't match type `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
                  with `Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types.Builder'
    Expected type: Source
                     (ResourceT IO) Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types.Builder
      Actual type: ConduitM
                     () Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString (ResourceT IO) ()
    In the return type of a call of `CB.sourceFile'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: CB.sourceFile "job.zip"
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { CB.sourceFile "job.zip" }'
```

The type of putObject is

```
putObject
  :: Bucket
     -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
     -> http-conduit-1.9.5.2:Network.HTTP.Conduit.Types.RequestBody
          (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO)
     -> PutObject
```

I can't see how a RequestBody ResourceT IO can be constructed since the possible constructors for RequestBody don't include a ResoureceT IO

```
data RequestBody m
  = RequestBodyLBS Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
  | RequestBodyBS Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
  | RequestBodyBuilder GHC.Int.Int64
                       Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types.Builder
  | RequestBodySource GHC.Int.Int64
                      (Data.Conduit.Internal.Source
                         m Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types.Builder)
  | RequestBodySourceChunked (Data.Conduit.Internal.Source
                                m Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types.Builder)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here (cleaned up a bit) is:

> Couldn't match type ByteString with Builder

So the first question is: how do you convert a ByteString to a Builder? [Using Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=ByteString+-%3E+Builder&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09) we get a few possible hits, and [fromByteString](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/blaze-builder/Blaze-ByteString-Builder-ByteString.html#v%3afromByteString) turns out to be the best.

The next question is how to transform a `Source` to yield a new type of value. This requires some understanding of conduit, for which I recommend [the conduit tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview). But the idea is to create a data transformer (a `Conduit`) that transforms an incoming stream of `ByteString`s and produces an outcoming stream of `Builder`s, and *fuse* that with the `Source`.

For the first step, we want to use the `map` abstraction from `Data.Conduit.List`. For the second, the fusion operator is `$=`. Putting it all together, we have:

```
CB.sourceFile "job.zip" $= Data.Conduit.List.map fromByteString
```

Comment: *Exactly* the issue I had. Thank you, thank you! Also, your libraries are great! :)